# How to reverse a GSAP animation without Timeline when animation is completed?

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, scrollbar, gsap

I just met with ScrollTrigger plugin which is the reason to use GSAP for me. I just want to give a smooth skew animation on Scrolling belongs to velocity. But I don't know how to reverse an animation without a timeline. I tried yoyo, it works but not stable. Sometimes it sticks on some angles. Any other way to handle this.

And, I know that I can put another GSAP animation to onComplete but it's not a clear way to handle this. I am looking for a fair solution.

```js
import { gsap } from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import './style.scss'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
gsap.set('.box', { transformOrigin: 'right center', force3D: true })

ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: '.grid',
  onUpdate: self => {
    const velocity = Math.round(self.getVelocity() / 300)

    gsap.to('.box', {
      skewY: velocity,
      duration: 0.2,
      yoyo: true,
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: You likely don't want to create a new tween every single update. See [this pen](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/eYpGLYL) for how to use the velocity. For any more help than that, please create a minimal demo.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the pen already. I just wanted to handle this with some other ways to discover more.